# How to reverse style edits of a web page in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

If the layout of a certain page is edited via 'Inspect Element', how can one restore the layout page to its original layout?

Example: One deletes links on a webpage through 'Inspect Element' and wishes to restore them weeks later. Here, a simple undo will not work. How can one restore the original view settings of this webpage?

Also, would opening the page in incognito-mode change the layout? In other words, could one open the page in incognito-mode and view an edit free version of a webpage?

Thanks

Comment: You can't remove anything permanently through inspect element.

Comment: Inspect element only affects your DOM not the server code.

Comment: How can these changes be saved locally and then reversed?

Comment: Not. You'll have to copy everything in text-files. http://superuser.com/questions/657335/save-inspect-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reload the page and the edits done will no longer be visible. You have only changed your local view of the page.

If you wish to save the changes you made, simply copy the modified HTML and paste it into a *.html file on your local filesystem. (note that relative paths for JavaScript files, images, stylesheets, etc. will no longer work, among other potential issues)

Comment: Yes you could save a copy to your PC, but this is a copy on another address. Changes to scripts would probably fail etc. I do not think this is what is being asked.

Comment: @JanJoukeTjalsma Agreed...if it is a very, very basic (HTML-only) page, then saving could be ok, but it is very likely that the saved version would not render as desired (due to scripts, images, stylesheets, server-side code, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Editing via "inspect element" should not save the page at all actually. A refresh should do to revert the changes.

Comment: Is there any way of saving changes to a webpage locally?

Comment: There are none that I know of. I think this is intended behaviour really. Otherwise someone, perhaps in an internet cafe, could alter pages with malicious code quite easily without the end-user knowing.